# How to add new foreign key column with default value to an existing table with data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

**I'm trying to achieve this:**

- Table A that has almost 100 records - to add a new column (eg: ID
  with default value 0)
- Creating a new table B for which ID is PK

**I tried this:**

- added ID column to `Table A` as null
- updated the old values as 0 for existing rows
- created `Table B` with ID as PK
- made ID column as not null in `Table A`
- tried to add FK constraint to `Table A`

**And got this error:**

- ORA-02298: cannot validate parent keys not found.

What am I missing here? Also, I cannot delete child records in `Table A`

Comment: What column in TAB_A is the foreign key constraint on? What table and column does the foreign key reference? Please edit your question (use the `edit` button located just above the tags) and add all of the statements you used to modify your tables, set values, etc. Thanks.

Comment: You missed the step where you add a row to Table B with id = 0.

Comment: The problem statement makes no sense. The whole point of a Foreign Key is to require the values in the column to be found in the Primary Key it references. What do you mean by "default value" for the Foreign Key? Do you already have values in the PK column (in the other table), and a distinguished row in the parent table, and you want - if a value is not provided for the FK - to use that distinguished row's PK value for the FK? **WHY??** What business need may possibly be served by such an arrangement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this Ask TOM article :  [**Constraint ENABLE/ DISABLE**](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8806498660292)

> You can enable or disable integrity constraints at the table level
>   using the CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement. You can also set
>   constraints to VALIDATE or NOVALIDATE, in any combination with ENABLE
>   or DISABLE

And from a related artice by Tim Hall: [**ORACLE-BASE**](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/constraint-checking-updates)

`ENABLE VALIDATE` is the same as ENABLE. The constraint is checked and is guaranteed to hold for all rows.

`ENABLE NOVALIDATE` means the constraint is checked for new or modified rows, but existing data may violate the constraint.

`DISABLE NOVALIDATE` is the same as DISABLE. The constraint is not checked so data may violate the constraint.

`DISABLE VALIDATE` means the constraint is not checked but disallows any modification of the constrained columns.

---

So, to answer your question

> "How to add new foreign key column with default value to an existing
>   table with data"

you may use option 2 **ONLY**  if you want that the constraint is checked, but it does not have to be
true for all rows. This allows existing rows to violate the constraint, while ensuring
that all new or modified rows are valid.

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES B(ID)  ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting scenario - CHILD_TABLE with 100 rows and no link to PARENT_TABLE:

```
create table parent_table (id integer constraint parent_pk primary key);

create table child_table (somecolumn integer);

insert into child_table select rownum from dual connect by rownum <= 100;
```

Now we want to link CHILD_TABLE to PARENT_TABLE with the default parent set to 0.

Add a value to PARENT_TABLE so that CHILD_TABLE can refer to it:

```
insert into parent_table (id) values (0);
```

If you don't add this value, it's like having a VEHICLES table with the default manufacturer as 'HONDA', but not defining 'HONDA' in the MANUFACTURERS table. The whole point of foreign keys is to stop you doing that.

Now add a foreign key to CHILD_TABLE (`default on null` is new in Oracle 12.1, but the plain `default` also works, however only recent versions of Oracle apply the default when adding a new column - I forget which version exactly.)

```
alter table child_table
add   parent_id integer
      default on null 0
      constraint child_parent_fk references parent_table ;
```

Check what we have in CHILD_TABLE now:

```
select * from child_table;

SOMECOLUMN PARENT_ID
---------- ---------
         1         0
         2         0
         3         0
         4         0
         5         0
         6         0
         7         0
         8         0
         9         0
        10         0
        11         0

...

100 rows selected
```

Check the status of the new FK:

```
select fk.constraint_name, fkc.column_name, fk.status
     , pk.table_name, fk.r_constraint_name
from   user_constraints fk
       join user_constraints pk
            on  pk.constraint_name = fk.r_constraint_name
            and pk.owner = fk.r_owner
       join user_cons_columns fkc
            on  fkc.table_name = fk.table_name
            and fkc.constraint_name = fk.constraint_name
where  fk.table_name = 'CHILD_TABLE'
and    fk.constraint_type = 'R'
and    pk.constraint_type = 'P';

CONSTRAINT_NAME    COLUMN_NAME         STATUS   TABLE_NAME          R_CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------ ------------------- -------- ------------------- -----------------
CHILD_PARENT_FK    PARENT_ID           ENABLED  PARENT_TABLE        PARENT_PK
```

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments. when I tried enable no validate it did work. But also adding a record in the parent table before enabling foreign key constraint will work too.